# How to resolve "Error fetching schema" in gqlgen

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

Good day, i am new to go and i am trying to build a graphql service with go, i did this using the go gqlgen package. Now when install and generate necessary files the initial start up, i can see the default TODO schema and resolver on the docs tab, when i implement or add additional schema to the schema file, i get "Error fetching schema" from the playground[image: play ground]

my schema file:

```
scalar Timestamp

type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  password: String!
  otp_code: String!
  role: String!
  status: String!
  isEmailVerified: Boolean!
  otp_expire_time: Timestamp!
  createdAt: Timestamp!
  updatedAt: Timestamp!
  deletedAt: Timestamp!
}

input LoginCredential {
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

input UserSignUpDetail {
  email: String!
  password: String!
}

type AuthResponse {
  access_token: String!
  refresh_token: String!
}

type Mutation {
  UserLogin(input: LoginCredential!): AuthResponse!
  UserSignUp(input: UserSignUpDetail!): User!
}
```

schema resolver file:

```
package graph

// This file will be automatically regenerated based on the schema, any resolver implementations
// will be copied through when generating and any unknown code will be moved to the end.

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "gatewayservice/graph/generated"
    "gatewayservice/graph/model"
)

// UserLogin is the resolver for the UserLogin field.
func (r *mutationResolver) UserLogin(ctx context.Context, input model.LoginCredential) (*model.AuthResponse, error) {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("not implemented: UserLogin - UserLogin"))
}

// UserSignUp is the resolver for the UserSignUp field.
func (r *mutationResolver) UserSignUp(ctx context.Context, input model.UserSignUpDetail) (*model.User, error) {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("not implemented: UserSignUp - UserSignUp"))
}

// Mutation returns generated.MutationResolver implementation.
func (r *Resolver) Mutation() generated.MutationResolver { return &mutationResolver{r} }

type mutationResolver struct{ *Resolver }
```

please i need assistance thanks..

Comment: You can share us your `server.go` like ? Where you initialize your generated srv.

Answer (score 0):

Expect `type Mutation`, you should add `type Query` (at least one method) to your *.graphql* file. For example, you can add this to your `schema.graphql`:

```
type Query {
   foo(bar: String!): String!
}
```

After, use *gqlgen* CLI to generate new **Go** files that would represent new *.graphql* schema.